# Iterating through arrays and map

Tags: javascript

"I am trying to get totalAmount of instrument for each days. I am having one array of objects, which contains instrumentId and dailyPrices as key.Instrument Id is simply a key value pair.Daily prices key is an object having key as date and value as price.I want to add one key to object as totalAmount(quatity * price for that date) by calculating time amount."

"I have tried grouping array by instrument id and fetching price for dates but its getting complicated. I tried multiple methods from underscore.js also."

```
let priceData = [{
    instrumentId: 7138,
    dailyPrices: {
      2019 - 02 - 01: 15.89,
      2019 - 02 - 02: 93.990,
      2019 - 02 - 03: 80.90
    }
  },
  {
    instrumentId: 7132,
    dailyPrices: {
      2019 - 02 - 01: 10.89,
      2019 - 02 - 02: 23.990,
      2019 - 02 - 03: 87.90
    }
  }
]

let responseObject = {
  2019 - 02 - 01: {
    7132 - 65: {
      instrumentId: 7132,
      quantity: 10
    },
    7138 - 69: {
      instrumentId: 7138,
      quantity: 18
    }
  },
  2019 - 02 - 03: {
    7132 - 65: {
      instrumentId: 7132,
      quantity: 13
    },
    7138 - 69: {
      instrumentId: 7138,
      quantity: 15
    }
  }

}
```

I want output like this

```
let responseObject = {
  2019 - 02 - 01: {
    7132 - 65: {
      instrumentId: 7132,
      quantity: 10,
      totalAmount: 108.9
    },
    7138 - 69: {
      instrumentId: 7138,
      quantity: 18,
      totalAmount: 286.02
    }
  },
  2019 - 02 - 03: {
    7132 - 65: {
      instrumentId: 7132,
      quantity: 13,
      totalAmount: 1142.7
    },
    7138 - 69: {
      instrumentId: 7138,
      quantity: 15,
      totalAmount: 1213.5
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: yes it is an instrumentId

Answer (score 0):

You could take the entries of `responseObject` and generate the wanted property by looking for the price.

At the end rebuild new objects.

```js
var priceData = [{ instrumentId: 7138, dailyPrices: { '2019-02-01': 15.89, '2019-02-02': 93.990, '2019-02-03': 80.90 } }, { instrumentId: 7132, dailyPrices: { '2019-02-01': 10.89, '2019-02-02': 23.990, '2019-02-03': 87.90 } }],
    responseObject = { '2019-02-01': { '7132-65': { instrumentId: 7132, quantity: 10 }, '7138-69': { instrumentId: 7138, quantity: 18 } }, '2019-02-03': { '7132-65': { instrumentId: 7132, quantity: 13 }, '7138-69': { instrumentId: 7138, quantity: 15 } } },
    result = Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(responseObject)
        .map(([k, o]) => [
            k,
            Object.fromEntries(Object
                .entries(o)
                .map(([l, q]) => [
                    l,
                    { ...q, totalAmount: q.quantity * priceData.find(p => q.instrumentId === p.instrumentId).dailyPrices[k] }
                ]))
        ]));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure, how you are calculating `totalPrice`. Looks like (and clarified later) `totalPrice` is calculated by multiplying `quantity` with `dailyPrice`.

By the way here are the techniques of iteration:

- An Array can be iterated using a plain `for loop` or using `[...array[.forEach(element =>{})`
- A Map can be iterated using `Object.keys(map).forEach(key=>{})`

Here is the runnable code:

```js
let priceData = [{ instrumentId: 7138, dailyPrices: { "2019 - 02 - 01": 15.89, "2019 - 02 - 02": 93.990, "2019 - 02 - 03": 80.90 } }, { instrumentId: 7132, dailyPrices: { "2019 - 02 - 01": 10.89, "2019 - 02 - 02": 23.990, "2019 - 02 - 03": 87.90 } }];
let responseObject = { "2019 - 02 - 01": { "7132 - 65": { instrumentId: 7132, quantity: 10 }, "7138 - 69": { instrumentId: 7138, quantity: 18 } }, "2019 - 02 - 03": { "7132 - 65": { instrumentId: 7132, quantity: 13 }, "7138 - 69": { instrumentId: 7138, quantity: 15 } } };
let priceIndex = {};
// Index prices by day and instrument id for quick access
[...priceData].forEach(price => {
    Object.keys(price.dailyPrices).forEach((key) => priceIndex[key + "-" + price.instrumentId] = price.dailyPrices[key])
});
Object.keys(responseObject).forEach(day => {
    Object.keys(responseObject[day]).forEach(token => {
        responseObject[day][token]['totalAmount'] = responseObject[day][token]['quantity'] * priceIndex[day + "-" + responseObject[day][token]['instrumentId']];
    });
});
console.log(responseObject);
```

Comment: i am calculating total price on multiplying quantity from responseObject with price of that date from matching that instrumentId from priceData. Can you help me now? @fiveelements

Comment: @VimleshKumar yes, the above solution does the multiplication. Please run it yourself and check the result.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the array into a hashtable first - as you have keys and its wasted computation to search for the keys O(ln) compared to O(1)

and then iterate through response and add either to the list or a new list(in example):

as a reminder: `for ... in` iterates over all iterables - also inherited ones

```js
let iterationCounter = 0;

let priceData = [{
    instrumentId: 7138,
    dailyPrices: {
      "2019 - 02 - 01": 15.89,
      "2019 - 02 - 02": 93.990,
      "2019 - 02 - 03": 80.90
    }
  },
  {
    instrumentId: 7132,
    dailyPrices: {
      "2019 - 02 - 01": 10.89,
      "2019 - 02 - 02": 23.990,
      "2019 - 02 - 03": 87.90
    }
  }
]
const flattedPriceData = {}
for(let {instrumentId, dailyPrices} of priceData){

  flattedPriceData[+instrumentId] = dailyPrices;
  iterationCounter++;
}


let responseObject = {
  "2019 - 02 - 01": {
    "7132 - 65": {
      instrumentId: 7132,
      quantity: 10
    },
    "7138 - 69": {
      instrumentId: 7138,
      quantity: 18
    }
  },
  "2019 - 02 - 03": {
    "7132 - 65": {
      instrumentId: 7132,
      quantity: 13
    },
    "7138 - 69": {
      instrumentId: 7138,
      quantity: 15
    }
  }

}

const resultResponse = {}
for(let currentDate in responseObject){
    const subObject = responseObject[currentDate]
    resultResponse[currentDate] = {}
    for(let weirdInstrumentId in subObject){
      iterationCounter++; 
      const subsubObject = subObject[weirdInstrumentId]
      resultResponse[currentDate][weirdInstrumentId] = {...subsubObject, cost: subsubObject.quantity * flattedPriceData[subsubObject.instrumentId][currentDate]}
    }
}

console.log(resultResponse)
console.log(iterationCounter, "iterations for 2 instruments and 2 days (2 + 2 * 2 - O(n)")
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```